# how to select children next to it in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="Return home">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="About the company">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">The product</a>
            <ul> // level 2
            <li><a href="#">x3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">x4</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Meet the team</a>
<ul> // level 2
            <li><a href="#">x1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">x2</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

using jquery i wanted to select ul of level 2 
like if i hover on 'The product' then i want to select only ul[level 2] that is next to it not all level 2 ul.

I use jQuery code to select like this

```
$('#nav li ul li').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').css('opacity','.5');
});
```

but this code effect on both level 2 ul i want to select the ul that is inside that `<li>` which is hover...

Comment: works for me, as I expected from reading the code - the only issue I can see is that it doesn't remove the CSS when you leave the `<li>`.  See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/mJvfj/

Comment: see if i initially set level 2 ul display:none then when i hover level 1 <li> then i want to show level 2 menu that inside of level 1 that i hover and if i change .css('opacity','.5'); to show(); and then i hover on 1st level first one then it will work fine after that i hover to next one then it will also showed it overlap the previous one

Answer (score 1):

Try this using **Child combinator selector**:

```
$('#nav > li > ul > li').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').css('opacity','.5');
});
```

This means it will only select list items that are direct children of an unordered list. In other words, it only looks one level down the markup structure, no deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Can do with CSS:

<kbd>[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/cUvGD/)</kbd>

```
#nav > li > ul > li:hover > ul {opacity:.5;}
```

Comment: Just about to say this myself, but be aware of cross-browser issues with the > selector, IE6 and below I think.